# Get list of full language names in Java

Tags: java

How can I get a list of full names of languages? I checked `Locale` class and found `getISOLanguages()`, but it returns 2-letter language codes (for instance, 'en') when I need full name of language (for example, 'English').

What is the better approach for that?

Comment: Try the `getDisplayLanguage()` method, probably best with a locale being passed, e.g. `Locale.GERMAN.getDisplayLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH)`. To get a list of all languages just iterate over the result of `getISOLanguages()` and do something like `new Locale(isoLang).getDisplayLanguage( Locale.ENGLISH )`. Just note that there might not be a name for each iso language.

Comment: Alternatively iterate over `Locale.getAvailableLocales()` which returns a list of all installed locales. Note that this might not return a locale for each language code but might return multiple locales for others (e.g. with country and regional parts).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally, thanks to Thomas comments I implemented it in such way:

```
SortedSet<String> allLanguages = new TreeSet<String>();
String[] languages = Locale.getISOLanguages();
for (int i = 0; i < languages.length; i++){
    Locale loc = new Locale(languages[i]);
    allLanguages.add(loc.getDisplayLanguage());
}
```

UPD. Also there is the more modern style:

```
Set<String> languages = Arrays.stream(Locale.getISOLanguages())
            .map(Locale::new)
            .map(Locale::getDisplayLanguage)
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));
```